# I want to ask about docker volume

Tags: docker, .net-core, docker-compose

I am trying to use docker for my project. Here is my docker compose:

```
version: '3'
services:
api:
  build: Api/
  ports:
  - "8080:80"
  - "8081:443"
  environment:
    ASPNETCORE_URLS: "https://+;http://+"
    ASPNETCORE_HTTPS_PORT: "8081"
    ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT: "Development"
  volumes:
    - ${APPDATA}\microsoft\UserSecrets\:/root/.microsoft/usersecrets
    - ${USERPROFILE}\.aspnet\https:/root/.aspnet/https/
server:
  build: Server/
  ports:
  - "8082:80"
  - "8083:443"
  environment:
    ASPNETCORE_URLS: "https://+;http://+"
    ASPNETCORE_HTTPS_PORT: "8083"
    ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT: "Development"
  volumes:
    - ${APPDATA}\microsoft\UserSecrets\:/root/.microsoft/usersecrets
    - ${USERPROFILE}\.aspnet\https:/root/.aspnet/https/
    - ./../src/:/src/
```

And my dockerfile for Server:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:5.0 AS build-env
WORKDIR /app/server

# Copy csproj and restore as distinct layers
COPY *.csproj ./
RUN dotnet restore

# Copy everything else and build
COPY . ./
RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o out

# Build runtime image
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:5.0
WORKDIR /app/server
COPY --from=build-env /app/server/out .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Server.dll"]
```

I want to copy the folder src to container in docker. Here is my physical in window:

```
samples:
   - server
     - Server.csproj
src:
   - ...
```

In docker, here is my container structure:

```
app:
   - api:
   - server:
      - Server.csproj
src:
```

In my Server.csproj:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <ProjectReference 
   Include="..\..\src\suite\OpenIddict.UI.Suite.Core\tomware.OpenIddict.UI.Suite.Core.csproj" 
   />
  ...
</ItemGroup>
```

I've noticed that it was able to copy all the files to the src folder in docker.
But I still get this error:  The referenced project '../../src/suite/OpenIddict.UI.Suite.Core/tomware.OpenIddict.UI.Suite.Core.csproj' does not exist

Please help !!! I'm stuck in this for a week !!!!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like one of your projects is outside of [docker context](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/dockerfile_best-practices/#understand-build-context). So your copy command `COPY *.csproj ./` doesn't see it.
As I understand, this project is some kind of a core library. In this case moving the project is not the best idea. Instead, you could consider putting it into a nuget package and then using that package instead of a project reference.